# Tienimi, tenetemi, tengami

Tags: verbs, word-choice, sentences, formal

I am unsure of the right usage, which is quite a basic question admittedly.

I assume that it works the following way : to address several people, whether there is a mark of reverence/politeness or not we say

```
Tenetemi informato
```

to address one person we are close to we say

```
Tienimi informato
```

and to address one person with a mark of reverence/politeness we say

```
Tengami informato
```

Is the assumption correct, or what is the right imperative construction for the various cases?

Comment: The last construction is very old-fashioned. I don't even think that anybody has *said* it; but it used to be employed in formal contexts such as letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. The usual form is

> Mi tenga informato.

or (just using a different verb):

> Mi mantenga informato.

That is, when using the formal addressing imperative, the pronoun goes before the verb as a word on its own, insted of becoming a suffix as you correctly do for the other cases.

Comment: I'll add that the analogous formal form, when addressing more than one person, is _mi tengano informato_ (3rd person plural), but it is now very rare, and most people use the 2nd person (_tenetemi_) even when addressing strangers.

Comment: @DaG thanks for reminding that. In my experience, the 3rd person plural formal form is very rare nowadays, but it's good to mention it for completeness.